# Java:How limit genericity?

Tags: java

I want to create a list which only add string or integer.

```
List L = new ArrayList();
L.add("string");
L.add(8);
```

I know `List<Object> L`,but I hope L only add string or integer.

Comment: **Why** do you want to do this? Create an immutable class with two optional fields (one `String` and one `Integer`), then make it a `List<MyOptionalType> al = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Or you can wrap a `List<Object>` and only expose `add()` overloads that accept `Integer` and `String`.

Comment: Why don't you create a List<String> and add Integer values by type casting. You can use Integer.toString(number) to convert Integer to String. When you are retrieving elements at a later time you can use Integer.parseInt("yourStringValue") method

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good solution to any problem.

Comment: Don't use lists as classes. Use classes as classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly the best solution (from a design standpoint) is to make a immutable union-like class as Elliott Frisch suggested. This option has the fewest avenues for weird expected-string-got-integer errors.

```
public class StringOrInt {
    public final Integer intVal;
    public final String stringVal;

    public StringOrInt(Integer i) {
        intVal = i;
        stringVal = null;
    }

    public StringOrInt(String s) {
        stringVal = s;
        intVal = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return stringVal == null && intVal == null;
    }

    public boolean isString() {
        return stringVal != null;
    }

    public boolean isInt() {
        return intVal != null;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (! (o instanceof StringOrInt)) return false;
      StringOrInt s = (StringOrInt) o;

      return isInt() && intVal.equals(s.intVal) || isString() && stringVal.equals(s.stringVal);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        if(isInt()) return intVal.hashCode();
        if(isString()) return stringVal.hashCode();
        return 0;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if(isInt()) return intVal.toString();
        if(isString()) return stringVal;
        return "EMPTY STRINGORINT";
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use a `List<StringOrInt>`, as so:

```
List<StringOrInt> lst = new ArrayList<>();
lst.add(new StringOrInt(5));
lst.add(new StringOrInt("Hello"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many use cases of this type, you better consider using other recommendations in the answer and comments area; they are clean too. But if your concern is only adding int or string values into a list:

- Define a method like

  ```
  public void add(final Object o, final List<Object> list) {
      if ((o instanceof String) || (o instanceof Integer)) {
          list.add(o);
      } else {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("You can add only values of type String or Integer.");
      }
  }
  ```
- Then call it as follows:

  ```
  List<Object> stringsOrInts = new ArrayList<Object>();
  add(8, stringsOrInts);
  add("String", stringsOrInts);
  ```